Why do newline characters get lost when concatenating strings ending with newline characters?
Scenario:
$ cat xxx.txt | od -c
0000000   x  \n   x  \n
0000004

$ value=""

# 1st iteration
$ value+="$(<xxx.txt)" ; echo "$value" | od -c
0000000   x  \n   x  \n
0000004

# 2nd iteration
$ value+="$(<xxx.txt)" ; echo "$value" | od -c
0000000   x  \n   x   x  \n   x  \n
0000007

At the 2nd iteration we see that \n after the 2nd x is lost. Why? How to prevent this?
The expected output is:
0000000   x  \n   x  \n   x  \n   x  \n
0000007


That "1st iteration" output is actually misleading (well, as is the second). The final newline you see is from echo. Use printf %s "$value" instead.

@muru Thanks. Then why after value="$(<xxx.txt)" the value doesn't contain the last newline character? How to fix?

The "why" is explained in the duplicate: command substitution $(...) removes trailing newlines. Sadly there is no fix, command substitution always does that. You can, however, try something like: value+=$(cat xxx.txt; printf x); value=${value%x} (add a trailing character to protect the newline, then remove it afterwards).

@muru Indeed, command substitution $(...) removes trailing newlines. TIL. FYI: user Stéphane Chazelas recommends using / rather than x.
